# How do I render Firestore collection using the Map function in React?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-component

I'm having a very hard time understanding how can I render data from a firestore collection. Here is what I am doing so far:
In /services/firestoreQueries:

```
const generateWishlist = (user) => {

    return db.collection('wishlist').where("username", "==", user.uid).get()

}
```

In my component file:

```
const ItemList = () => {
const {currentUser} = useAuth()
const [list, setList] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
    generateWishlist(currentUser).then((snapshot) => {
        snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => (

            setList(prevState => ({
                list: [...prevState.list, doc.data()]
            }))

            ))
    })
}, [currentUser])

console.log(list)


return (
    <div>
    <div>
        <h1>This is your wishlist!</h1>
    </div>
    </div>

)
}
```

I get a prevState.list is not iterable error.

If I comment out the code block inside snapshot and console.log(list), I get the data as expected, but when I try and map it, it says that list.map is not a function

Any idea why this may be happening? Any help would be appreciated! I've spent a little close to a whole day but no progress >.<

console.log when it returns data

```
[] ItemList.js:23 
{description: "i am testing", username: "CLmf7rX6I2YQsuAojqsJ3uWGqHD3", price: "10", item: "testing", live: true, …} ItemList.js:23 
{description: "i am testing", username: "CLmf7rX6I2YQsuAojqsJ3uWGqHD3", price: "10", item: "testing", live: true, …} ItemList.js:23
```

Comment: Post your console.log here

Comment: @Pushkin I have added my console.log in the details - please check. It returns data, but not in the list format, which is what I'd want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is not in `.map`, the error is in `setList`

You have created list as an array

```js
const [list, setList] = useState([])
```

But when you're setting it, you're changing it to an object

```js
setList(prevState => ({
   list: [...prevState.list, doc.data()]
}))

// list => {list: [...]}
```

Use `setList` as a hook and not as `this.setState`

```js
setList(prev => ([...prev, doc.data()])
```

Comment: Hi @Pushkin, thanks for your answer, but it gives me a TypeError: prevState.list is not iterable - see log below

(anonymous function)
src/components/ItemList.js:13
  10 | generateWishlist(currentUser).then((snapshot) => {
  11 |  snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => (
  12 |   //setList(doc.data())
> 13 |   setList(prevState => ([...prevState.list, doc.data()]))
     | ^  14 |   //console.log(doc.data())
  15 |   ))
  16 | })

Comment: Sorry, made a typo. Check now. It should have been just `prevState`, not `prevState.list`